# Load dictionary from np.load()

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pickle

I have a dictionary and I saved it to a file.

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
with open('testdata.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f,a)
```

When I attempt to load it back, it returns as unreadable

```
b = np.load('testdata.pickle',allow_pickle=True)
print(b)       #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
print(type(b)) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(b.shape) #()
print(len(b))  #Traceback (most recent call last):
               #File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
               #TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

How can I access this dictionary?

Trying to access the dictionary directly also fails.

```
>>> b['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you think the shape should be?  You're not saving an array you're saving a dictionary

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `np.load` / `np.save` to load a pickle of a dictionary?

Comment: I added code trying to access dictionary directly @sedavidw

Comment: `np.save` and `np.load` are for saving and loading NumPy arrays. They are not a general object serialization interface.

Comment: In any case, if you do use `np.load` and `np.save` it will serialize/deserialize your objects as numpy arrays, so in this case, a `numpy` scalar object with dtype=object which is just your dict. This really makes no sense to do things this way. Just use `pikcle` or even JSON

Comment: Thank you. I'll just use pickle.dump and pickle.load

Comment: The use of `save/load` for a python object like a dict isn't bad; you just have to deal with the single element array wrapper.  `item()` as mentioned in one of the answers is a simple way.  Under the array wrapper, `save` is using the standard pickle.  Conversely saving an array with `pickle` ends up using the `save` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As juanpa.arrivillaga said, I should not be using np.save/load.
pickle.dump and pickle.load is better

```
with open('testdata.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)


b = pickle.load(open('testdata.pickle','rb'))

print(b) #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do a `numpy.load()`, and you want the item stored within that file, you need to use `.item()`. In this case, you want `b.item()`

Comment: Thank you so much. My .npz was consisted of all dictionaries and a code like: data['arr_0'].item(0) opened my first dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It's because numpy stores the dictionary as an array. You're saving a dictionary as a numpy object, which by default, are arrays.
You can either simply use :

```
d = b.ravel()[0]
```

Which basically gets the dictionary out of the array. You can then use compatible dictionary operations.

But if you're going to be primarily saving and loading dictionaries, I'd recommend using pickle instead.

Comment: You could index that 0d array with `b[()]`.

Comment: Didn't know that one. Good tip. Thanks!